# Bootstrap 4 spacers

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Для чего нужен данный блок в Bootsrap 4 и как выставлять правильные значения в нем

```
$spacer:   1rem !default;
$spacer-x: $spacer !default;
$spacer-y: $spacer !default;
$spacers: (
  0: (
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  ),
  1: (
    x: $spacer-x,
    y: $spacer-y
  ),
  2: (
    x: ($spacer-x * 1.5),
    y: ($spacer-y * 1.5)
  ),
  3: (
    x: ($spacer-x * 3),
    y: ($spacer-y * 3)
  )
)
```

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/

Comment: а можно более менее внятный пример, на сайте что-то не очень понятно

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363194/how-do-i-use-the-spacing-utility-classes-on-bootstrap-4-using-meteorjs-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведенный в вопросе блок относится к новым утилитам Bootstrap 4 – spacers, или "вставки", "прокладки".

Данная утилита предназначена для удобной адаптивной настройки полей (margin) или отступов (padding) элемента. Введены эти классы (в версию 4) потому, что поля и отступы (не считая шрифтов и цветов) - наиболее часто переопределяемые элементы Bootstrap.

Например, если вам не нужно нижнее поле в `navbar`, теперь достаточно добавить к `navbar` класс `mb-0` (собственно, "mb" - это сокращение от "margin-bottom"). Можно настраивать поля и отступы как угодно – сверху, снизу, справа, слева, со всех сторон.

Еще пример: класс `mx-3` установит левое и правое поля элемента (при значении $spacer по умолчанию) в 1rem.

Для отступов классы соответственно начинаются с p: `.pt` (padding-top), `.pl` (padding-left)  и т.д.

**Ниже – полный список.**

Классы именуются по формату `{свойство}{стороны}-{размер}` для `xs` и `{ свойство}{ стороны}-{брейкпойнт}-{размер}` для `sm, md, lg и xl`.

**Свойства:**

- **m** – для классов, устанавливающих поля margin
- **p** – для классов,
  устанавливающих отступы padding

**Стороны:**

- **t** - для классов, устанавливающих margin-top или padding-top
- **b** - для классов, устанавливающих margin-bottom или padding-bottom
- **l** - для классов, устанавливающих margin-left или padding-left
- **r** - для классов, устанавливающих margin-right или padding-right
- **x** - для классов, устанавливающих оба *-left и *-right
- **y** - для классов, устанавливающих оба *-top и *-bottom
- **blank** - для классов, устанавливающих margin или padding на всех 4 сторонах элемента

И **размер** – одно из следующих значений (можно добавить собственные при помощи переменной $spacers в SASS):

- 0 - для классов, убирающих margin или padding (они ставятся на 0)
- 1 - (по умолчанию) для классов, устанавливающих margin или padding в значение $spacer-x * .25 или $spacer-y * .25
- 2 - (по умолчанию) для классов, устанавливающих margin или padding в значение $spacer-x * .5 или $spacer-y * .5
- 3 - (по умолчанию) для классов, устанавливающих margin или padding в значение $spacer-x или $spacer-y
- 4 - (по умолчанию) для классов, устанавливающих margin или padding в значение $spacer-x * 1.5 or $spacer-y * 1.5
- 5 - (по умолчанию) для классов, устанавливающих margin или padding в значение $spacer-x * 3 or $spacer-y * 3

Также предусмотрен класс для центрирования по горизонтали: `mx-auto` (применяется к блочному элементу с установленной шириной).

Подробнее: документация Bootstrap 4 https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/